# xcode_backend.sh: no such file or directory. Do I need to create this file?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, ios-simulator

My Flutter Project won't run on the ios simulator and is throwing this error:

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
>
> Running Xcode build...
>
> Xcode build done.                                            7.6s
>
> Failed to build iOS app
>
> Error output from Xcode build:
>
> ↳
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:

> ↳
>
> === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>
> /bin/sh: /Users/pinercode/AndroidStudioProjects/bmi-calculator-flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator.
>
> Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.

The xcode error was also as follows:

> /bin/sh: /Users/pinercode/AndroidStudioProjects/bmi-calculator-flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

I've already tried running flutter doctor and there were no errors.
I also tried re-rooting my xcode 'FLUTTER_ROOT' and 'FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH' in build settings, which did not work.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

after a lot of messing around, I set these two settings and the build ran on to my physical device.

- Goto Xcode,
- click on Runner
- select Project (top one)
- go to Info tab
- change configurations for debug
- top Runner (green icon) to `Generated`
- Bottom Runner (red circles) `Pods-Runner-debug`

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue.

Comment: Solved my issue also. I was facing same error after upgrading to XCode 13. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Comment: Working fine! thanks

Comment: after a whole day debugging this solved my issue. but why? what the heck is going on? why is iOS dx this ugly? ugh...

Comment: After spending few days, Only your solution worked.

Comment: the same thing with release

Comment: no comment ( for Xcode ) .... but thanks its works!

Answer (score 63):

use this settings:

1. Open Xcode - Click on Runner(Top one)
2. Select the Runner from "PROJECT" Not from "TARGETS"
3. Select configuration
4. And update all the modes as this photo

[image]

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. That made it clearer for me. IOS dev environment is horrible

Answer (score 47):

Basically what happens is that one of the project's 'Build Phases' is running a script:

```
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
```

Now in order to find `xcode_backend.sh` the FLUTTER_ROOT variable needs to be defined. It is defined in a file called `Flutter/Generated.xcconfig`, which is generated when you run `flutter pub get` or `flutter build`.

The build configuration files `Debug.xcconfig` and `Release.xcconfig` (in the same Flutter folder) include `Generated.xcconfig`.
Now the only thing left is to ensure that for each of the project configurations these build configuration files are properly set (in XCode under Project > Info > Configuration).

Comment: I am not quite clear, does this mean that mean we just want to ensure that a configuration file is set for each target? https://a.cl.ly/YEuk4Qjq

Answer (score 23):

Open Xcode
Click on Runner(Top one)
Select the Runner from "PROJECT" Not from "TARGETS"
Select configuration
And update all the modes for ex: In debug select "debug" configuration set

[image]

Comment: nice one, thanks!

Comment: The image helped, thanks

Answer (score 13):

By Setting **FLUTTER_ROOT** as the Flutter sdk path solved this issue for me.

[image]

Comment: The other and simpler solution was to add this line in the file 'Runner/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig':

#include "Generated.xcconfig"

Comment: i didn't know that :(

Comment: I had changed my flutter path (to support different versions of dart), and this was set to the non-existent path. Set it right, and works great!

Comment: For some reason my `FLUTTER_TARGET` was defined as a very wrong value. Thank you for including it in your screenshot.

Answer (score 8):

Setting runner to Generated in project->Info Configurations seemed to fix it. I can build in xcode now.

Comment: This fixed the problem and it build successfully. However, I had to update my Xcode version to the latest to support the latest version on my iPhone.

Comment: That's the fix for me. I set project runner to generated and target runner to None.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution was to call

flutter clean

flutter run

and then run the app from Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me was going under `PROJECT` -> `Info` -> `Configurations`

setting the following:

```
Debug:
    Runner - None
    fRunner - Debug

Release:
    Runner - None
    fRunner - Release 

Profile:
    Runner - None
    fRunner - Generated
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this! Thank me later. Follow the steps in screenshot, set release to release, debug to debug.

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

If changing the configuration as suggested above doesn't fix things

In your Build Phase scripts / Xcode Project change

```
$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/...
```

to

```
${FLUTTER_ROOT}/packages/flutter_tools/...
```

Did the trick for me after the upgrade to the new version of flutter broke the Build.

Answer (score 1):

i have this intermittently while setting up flavors havent got an answer on fixing it but the best explanation of the trail is here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49495

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

1. Removing my project ios folder.

(Save it elsewhere, as you will probably want to keep your Info.plist file and Podfile.)

2. Run `flutter create .` to build a new ios folder.
3. Replace new Info.plist and Podfile with originals.

(If you have firebase in your app as I did you likely will have to go into xcode and right-click on runner, add files to runner, and add your GoogleService-Info.plist)

4. `flutter clean` , `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions but no one worked :( , I think there is a something missing in the flutter folder so the fast simple solution is ;)

1. delete flutter folder
2. Download the stable branch straight from GitHub instead of using an archive (url: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos)

> git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable

3. Verify that the flutter/bin directory is in your PATH by running
   echo $PATH
4. flutter upgrade
   flutter config enable-ios
   flutter config enable-android
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   flutter doctor -v
5. cd path/your_project_name

> flutter run ios -t lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0):

My Flutter project was setup to use FVM (Flutter Version Manager) and the FLUTTER_ROOT variable in `Project > Build Settings` needed to be updated to use the correct version e.g. `/Users/<username>/fvm/versions/<version>`.