# Is there a way to solve the following error?

Tags: flutter

I have flutter already installed, but when I run flutter doctor, I get the following error

> /Users/mac/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter: line 56:
> /Users/mac/Developer/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: No such file or
> directory

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56844012/2932052

Comment: You may also google `flutter shared.sh "No such file or directory"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcode\_backend.sh: no such file or directory. Do I need to create this file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844012/xcode-backend-sh-no-such-file-or-directory-do-i-need-to-create-this-file)